# Python counting words in large file

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, memory, python-2.7

I have a 6M row database(sqlite) containing 4 fields: id(integer)|title(text)|text(text)|tags(text).

Now I need to count the occurrence of each word appeared in title for example and import into other tables such as word|count and tag|word|count.

My code looks like this in Python 2.7:

```
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
from collections import Counter
import sqlite3

word_count = Counter()
pair_count = Counter()

conn = sqlite3.connect('database')
c = conn.cursor()

for query in c.execute('SELECT Tags, Title FROM data'):
    tags = query[0].strip().split()
        title = wordpunct_tokenize(query[1])
        for word in title:
            word_count[word] += 1
            for tag in tags:
                pair_count[(tag, word)] += 1
...
```

The problem is that the counters goes so large that I got a memory error in 1M rows. I've tried to reinitialize the counters every 100K rows and adding the counts to the db file, but this approach seems to be very slow maybe due to the enormous number of tag-word pairs.

```
...
for query in c.execute('SELECT Tags, Title FROM data'):
    i += 1
    if i % 100000 == 0:
        conn1 = sqlite3.connect('counts.db')
        c1 = conn1.cursor()

        # update word count
        for word in word_count:
            c1.execute('SELECT Count FROM word_count WHERE Word=?', (word,))
            count = c1.fetchone()
            # add to existing count and update
            if count:
                count = word_count[word] + count[0]
                c1.execute('UPDATE word_count SET Count=? WHERE Word=?', (count, word))
            # insert new row
            else:
                c1.execute('INSERT INTO title_word_count VALUES (?,?)', (word, word_count[word]))

        # update pair count                
        for pair in pair_count:
            c1.execute('SELECT Count FROM pair_count WHERE Tag=? AND Word=?', pair)
            count = c1.fetchone()
            if count:
                count = pair_count[pair] + count[0]
                c1.execute('UPDATE pair_count SET Count=? WHERE Tag=? AND Word=?', (count, pair[0], pair[1]))
            else:
                c1.execute('INSERT INTO pair_count VALUES (?,?,?)', (pair[0], pair[1], pair_count[pair]))
        conn1.commit()
        conn1.close()

        # reinitiate counters
        word_count = Counter()
        pair_count = Counter()
...
```

Is there any approach I can follow to resolve this problem without access to multiple machines? Also any suggestions on the code would be appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to index the `counts.db` and update each batch, but it's still too slow - It took 10 hrs to process 7 batches of 200000 rows each.

I ended up by following my initial idea. But instead of updating the counts every 100K rows, I just insert them into table `subcounts` despite possible duplicate `Tag, Word` pair.

Then `INSERT INTO pair_count SELECT Tag, Word, SUM(Count) FROM subcounts GROUP BY Tag, Word;` gave me the final result. It took me about 3 hrs total.

I accidentally dropped the temporary table I got following @abernert suggestion, but I think it's doable.

Thank @Steve and @abernert for your advices!

Comment: Just checking the obvious: do you have the right indexes on the tables in `counts.db`?

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm not sure what you mean. `counts.db` store tables recording tag counts, word counts, and pair counts.

Comment: OK, in that case you probably need to research the topic of "SQL indexes". If you don't have them, then each query potentially scans the entire table, and you're doing two queries per pair count.

Comment: @SteveJessop I looked at SQL indexes, do you mean that I can index the pairs so that each query can find the row efficiently? What about `UPDATE` and `INSERT`? I've read about them being slow.

Comment: @RayXiao: An index turns a query from linear to logarithmic, but turns an insert from constant to logarithmic. If you don't understand what that means: Assume you have 1000000 rows. An index (on an appropriate key column) makes your queries take 20 steps instead of 1000000, but also makes your inserts take 20 steps instead of 1. Multiple indexes make things more complicated, and updates are always complicated (because the indexes speed up the WHERE clause, but slow down the SET clause).

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't see how an index is going to help. He has multiple values in a single column, which he has to split out with `str.split` and `wordpunct_tokenize`. An index can only index the whole column as a single value. He need to normalize the data first—and then, if it's too slow, he might need to add an index (not on that table, but on the `Count` table).

Comment: @abarnert I think Steve meant the same thing.

Comment: @abernert: I meant that the reason the questioner's current code is incredibly slow is the lack of indexes in the `counts.db` file (which is reasonably normal-form, unlike the `database` file: the former does not have multiple values in a single column). Just making `Word` unique in `word_count` and `(Tag, Word)` unique in `pair_count` should make this perform tolerably. Of course you're correct that there are more *elegant* ways of representing the input data, but it is not *necessary* to do any further normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had the rows in order by (Tag, Word), then you would get all of the updates for one pair count, then all of the updates for the next, and so on.

Unfortunately, because you haven't properly normalized your data, you can't get that.

If you don't know what that last sentence means, you need to read up on database normalization. [Third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) at Wikipedia looks like a good place to start.

If you can't fix your data model, we can build a temporary table to fix it:

```
c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _data')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE _data (Tag, Word)')
for query in c.execute('SELECT Tags, Title FROM data'):
    tags = query[0].strip().split()
    words = wordpunct_tokenize(query[1])
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO _data (Tag, Word) VALUES(?, ?)',
                  itertools.product(tags, words))
c.commit()
```

You don't actually *need* to split out both columns, just whichever one is larger. But this is much cleaner, unless you really need to save disk space.

Anyway, now you can `ORDER BY` either `Tag, Word` or `Word, Tag`, depending on which one is larger, and you don't need to keep a whole slew of `tag_count` values around, just the one you're currently working on. You'll get all the rows for one value, then all the rows for the next, and so on.

Which also means that with a `GROUP BY`, you can just let sqlite3 do the counting for you.

Which also means you don't need to iterate in Python in the first place; you can let sqlite3 do that too:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO pair_count 
             SELECT Tag, Word, COUNT(*) FROM _data GROUP BY Tag, Word''')
```

Comment: This works fine at first. I got a 100 GB database containing all `Tag, Word` pairs and tried to let sqlite do the counting. The query ran for a while and then throw an error "**database or disk is full**". I've got at least another 100 GB on the disk and the counts should not take more than that.

Comment: Which "this" are you referring to, iterating over an ORDER BY so you don't need to keep more than one tag in memory at once, iterating over a GROUP BY so you just get the number of rows per word each tag (or vice-versa) instead of each row, or doing the whole thing in SQL? The first two would let you see whether you're getting 90% of the way through or 5%, which might be helpful here.

Comment: Also, if you're using the pure-SQL version, can you run the `SELECT` statement and iterate over the results to see if you get an error either in the query itself or in fetching the results? And can you check the page size? You get, IIRC, 1G pages; with a 512-byte page that means 512GB for both tables and any temporary table it needs. (`PRAGMA page_size` will show the answer, and `PRAGMA page_size = 16384` will set it if you run it before any tables are created, and in most cases, `PRAGMA page_size=16384; VACUUM` will re-page an existing db. You might also want to see `PRAGMA page_count`.)

Comment: "this" meant everything before `INSERT INTO pair_count SELECT Tag, Word, COUNT(*) FROM _data GROUP BY Tag, Word`. I ran this query directly in sqlite3 rather than python. `PRAGMA page_size` gave me `4,096` and `PRAGMA page_count` is `26,980,838`. I'm running the `SELECT` query now in python to see whether the error occur before fetching.

Comment: @RayXiao: Depending on what you find (whether the query itself is too big, or inserting that many rows in a single transaction is hitting a limit, or…) you might be able to do a hybrid solution, where you batch up, say, every 10000 rows at a time from the `SELECT`, then `executemany` an INSERT and `commit`? Or you may have to do the batching in the query itself, using `LIMIT` and `>=` on the row id?